# Android application high CPU usage and Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Every time in logcat it showing `GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 274K, 13% free 2730K/3128K, paused 76ms, total 78ms` it means Heap related issue. When i am upgrading my Heap I am getting [image] and unable to ressolve the same issues. 
One more thing in device  getting CPU status more like [image]

So , please suggest me how i can ressolve my problem.
I all ready checked with static value ,images sizes,fragment transaction, timer etc.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: If you could show us some code of where your application is getting this memory leak that would be helpful. But if you can't, this should be helpful: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: Thank you.. i allready check that n got the First image and problem details. I am getting confusion Exactly at wchich line I am getting This issue.